# epub validation in php

Tags: php, validation, epub

Every where I got the link http://code.google.com/p/epubcheck/ ,
but I don't know how to use the downloaded files from there.

My requirement is validate ePub file in php using same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, download the [Rlease Binary](http://epubcheck.googlecode.com/files/epubcheck-1.0.5.zip), extract the zip file and read the file README.txt which is included. It explains how to run it on the command line.

Maybe you can use PHP to call the tool using the command line but I'm not sure.

There is also a [Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/epubcheck) where you can ask for help.

Comment: There is a discussion in the google group on how to use it with PHP: http://groups.google.com/group/epubcheck/browse_thread/thread/c8ac9abad43d8146/

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to have a way to check and log a ton of epubs, and in CLI, not with PHP.